# Where is System.Web.Helpers.Chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts, .net-assembly

I'm trying to follow the tutorial [Displaying Data in a Chart with ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor)](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart) using MVC4.
According to [Chart documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.chart(v=vs.111).aspx) it is located at the assembly System.Web.Helpers (in System.Web.Helpers.dll) but after adding it to my project I cant't find that class.
Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

From Reference Manager > Assemblies > Extensions, add reference to System.Web.Helpers

Import the namespace:

```
 using System.Web.Helpers;
```

Using the Chart class, create an instance:

```
 Chart myChart = new Chart(600, 400);
```